# accessoryButton with Instruments automation

Tags: iphone, automation, ios, instruments

I'm writing some automation .js file, and I need to tap one of my accessoryButton from one cell.

How can I send the tap message to it ?

This is a custom cell, but the accessoryButton is added by iOS, not by me, and I don't know wich name it has.

Also in the docs I couldn't find anything ...

I have the cell referenced correcly as I can change the textField value for example.

Thanks in advance,

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at the `buttons` property on your `UIATableCell`.  That should give you the buttons in your cell and you can probably get to the accessoryButton from there.  `UIATableCell` does not seem to have a specific property for the accessoryButton (cf. [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATableCellClassReference/UIATableCellClassReference/UIATableCellClassReference.html)).

Source: [Apple UIAElement Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAElementClassReference/UIAElement/UIAElement.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIAElement/buttons)

Comment: I'm having problems iterating through the buttons, I've opened a new question about it, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975367/instruments-automation-iterate-for-all-buttons